# javascript sessionStorage doesn't get element, set in PHP

Tags: javascript, php

There is a PHP value from a form, that I've set to the session. In my javascript code, I want to be able to access this value, but it doesn't work.

```js
    'use strict';
    let numOfPlayers = Number(sessionStorage.getItem('numOfPlayers'));//This returns 0
    alert(numOfPlayers);
```

```php
    <?php
      session_start();
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <?php
      if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
        $numOfPlayers = $_POST['numOfPlayers'];
        $_SESSION['numOfPlayers'] = $numOfPlayers;//It works until here
      }
    ?>
    <html>
    <body>
      <!--Code-->
      <script src="Script.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: PHP `$_SESSION` is unrelated to browser `sessionStorage` - the only thing they have in common is the word session

Comment: `sessionStorage` != `$_SESSION`. I think you've got your concepts / tools mixed up.

Comment: What @JaromandaX just said, the browser's sessionStorage and PHP's session are two different things. You'll have to share the information you want (by printing a js script block via PHP, a js readable cookie, etc).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to connect between the sessionStorage in PHP to JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45211303/how-to-connect-between-the-sessionstorage-in-php-to-js)

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO! As some of the other answers have already stated, Browser `sessionStorage` that is accessible via `JavaScript` and other client scripting languages, is not the same as `PHP` `$_SESSION` storage accessible on the server side. [When should I use PHP Session vs Browser Local Storage vs JavaScript Object Parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24438404/when-should-i-use-php-session-vs-browser-local-storage-vs-javascript-object-para)

However, here is an example that would take the `PHP` session variable value of `$_SESSION['numOfPlayers'];` and set that as a `JavaScript` variable `numOfPlayersPHPSession`, that in turn could be set into client session storage (this won't work on SO or most online tools as session/local storage is typically locked down, but you should be able to test locally assuming proper permissions/config).

Also, this is a loose example, so you would still need to make sure and follow best security practices when rendering `PHP` values into `JS` variables to be used in client side scripting, etc.

```
<?php
  session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
  if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    // Use null coalesce to make sure we set a value / 0 if no players
    $numOfPlayers = $_POST['numOfPlayers'] ?? 0;
    $_SESSION['numOfPlayers'] = $numOfPlayers; //It works until here
  }
?>
<html>
    <body>
        <!--Code-->
        <!--<script src="Script.js"></script>-->
        <script type="text/javascript">
            // In place of calling Script.js, embedding code here for example
            let numOfPlayersPHPSession = <?php echo $_SESSION['numOfPlayers']; ?>;
            sessionStorage.setItem('numOfPlayers', numOfPlayersPHPSession);
            let numOfPlayers = Number(sessionStorage.getItem('numOfPlayers'));
            // alert(numOfPlayers); or console.log(numOfPlayers);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

If you go to the example at the below link and click "Execute code" (which has some of the `$_SESSION` / `$_POST` logic commented out due to sandbox limitations), you will see that the value of `5` is set on a `JS` variable coming from the PHP session value, and then that could be set into `sessionStorage`. http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/285dbdec5446316c712dd49f895039eec8c4c915

[image]

Another item of note, if using client `sessionStorage`, you may want to add additional checks to your `JS` logic to ensure the browser window / application supports I/O with local/session storage, as outlined here: [Most elegant way to check sessionStorage support?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7192405/most-elegant-way-to-check-sessionstorage-support)

Answer (score 0):

`sessionStorage` uses client-side storage and PHP `$_SESSION` is stored on server-side.
You can access this value to sending AJAX request to server to get the session value from server-side